# Google Geocoder clientKey

Tags: java, google-maps-api-3

Can any one tell me what us clientKey in the Google Geocoder API call

Geocoder  geocoder = new Geocoder("clientID", "clientKey");

I have clientID but don't know what I suppose to be passed as clientKey

Answer (score 0):

`clientID` is a premium plan ID; for those who have premium plan with Google Maps API.

[More info on ID and Key here.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key)

As for `clientKey`, it is quite likely a custom set up for privacy on server side (environment variable perhaps); server side cryptokey- used in wrapping web service requests and keep the key hidden.

[Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/client-library) - This document will explain more on using client for Google Maps Services.

Comment: Thank you!, yes My premium plan did give me the clientID, but have not yet shared the clientKey. With out this the service call ends up with http error 403. I would request the provider for the client key